# Как обрезать углы у фотографии при помощи css

Tags: css3, вёрстка

Необходимо обрезать угол у фотографии (не согнуть). Возможно ли это сделать при помощи css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Визуально выглядит как отрезанный угол. На деле поверх угла кладется непрозрачный треугольник.

CSS:

```
.corner {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
 }

 .corner img {
   width: 200px;
 }

 .corner:after {
   content: '';
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-top: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid #fff;
   border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
```

}

HTML:

```
<div class="corner">
  <img src="img.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 2):

1) Добавить туда див с уголком цвета фона.
2) распечатать фотку на N дивах, где N - максимальная длина катета угла.
Второе решение - супертяжелое, но зато будет работать везде
3) напечатать фотку в качестве [бэкграунда](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) + в качестве [картинки бордера](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp). Потом использовать фишки из [CSS Shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: Фон не однородный. 3 вариант сейчас попробую реализовать.